# how to find intersection of a linked list and a BST in O(n1+n2)?

Tags: c

Algorithm that calculates intersection of a given linked list and a BST. Intersection must be found while traversing the tree

Answer (score 0):

Hash all the node addressed using `unordered_map<Node*>` and then traverse BST  to see if any node is in hash or not. If not, then there is no intersection, else return the common node we just found.